# How can i make array of json object from list in C#?

Tags: c#, json, httpclient

I have to call API to check the user address .need to use a post request with an array of JSON objects.

Below the function, I'm getting user information and here I have to create an array of the JSON objects and call the ValidateAddress function.
I am getting two addresses for the current user

```
public virtual CheckUserResult AddressErrors(User user ){
    var addressList  = new List<Address>();
    foreach (var userData in user.Address)
            {
                addressList.add(userData)
                   
            }
     var addressErrors = userClient.ValidateAddress(addressList);       
   
}
```

here I'm making HTTP post request to validate the user address

```
public virtual IList<> ValidateAddress(Address[] addressList)
        {
        //http post 
        
        }
    }
```

class

```
public class Address
    {
        
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public int pincode { get; set; }
    }
```

I suppose to get output like this

```
[{
                "state" : "A",
                "city" : "B",
                "pincode" : 1,

},
{
                 "state" : "E",
                "city" : "F",
                "pincode" : 2
}]
```

MY postman request was like this need to make the same thing in c# code with HTTP client

```
var client = new RestClient("http://test/api/useraddresscheck");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "59398d8b-b5c6-c244-9db7-0e690104048c");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Client_Secret", "abc");
request.AddHeader("Client_ID", "erd");
request.AddParameter("undefined", "[{\n \"state\" : \"A\",\n \"city\" : \"B\",\n \"pincode\" : 1,\n \"fulladdress\" : \"\"\n},\n{\n \"state\" : \"E\",\n \"city\" : \"F\",\n \"pincode\" : 2,\n \"fulladdress\" : \"\"\n}]\n", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

How do I make a list of JSON(key-value pair objects )and make a post request with httpclient?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a newer version of .NET you should use the HttpClient.
Also Properties in C# should always written in PascalCase, the serializer should take care of converting it into Camelcase. You can set it manually via the JsonPropertyNameAttribute.

Example usage:

```
public class MyService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public MyService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task DoStuff(MyData data)
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("ServerUri", data);

        // Handle response
    }
}

public class MyData
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("customName")]
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to c# so can you please explain me with my code so that I will get some better idea .if you don't mind please do this needful.